# Joining more than 2 datasets in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I am creating a report from MS CRM, I need to show data from 3 different tables. I can join 2 datasets using **lookup** but I don't know how to show fields from 3 datasets?

Datasource is **CRM > Fetch XML**
We are not using SQL query so can't join tables in one query. If the solution is multilookup, then please let me know the way to write **multilookup** OR is there any other way?

Second problem is: when I am creating a report with report wizard, I am able to integrate the report in MS CRM but when i am creating the report without wizard, CRM shows the below error:

> This report type is not supported. Microsoft Dynamics 365 Online supports only reports that use Fetch XML data sources. If you contact support, please provide the technical details.

Comment: The only way I have benn able to get data from three datasets was to first use a lookup and then use a second lookup (in another column) using the reportitem of the previous column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way: To perform inner join in FetchXML query & set the following attributes in link-entity clause.

1.set **name** attribute to logical name of related entity

2.set **to** attribute to linking attribute in primary entity

3.set **from** attribute to linking attribute in related entity

4.set **link-type** attribute to inner

5.within link-entity clause specify attributes from related entity to retrieve.

```
      <link-entity name='account'  to='parentcustomerid' from='accountid' link-type='inner'>
```

Ref: http://blog.msxrmtools.com/2016/04/inner-join-in-fetchxml-fetchxml-query.html?m=1